# concat() how to query search a string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table setup with the following rows:

```
orderfrom                               | Name
-------------------------------------------------------
ClearVision, Oakley, I-Deal Optics      | ClearVision
ClearVision                             | I-Deal Optics
ClearVision                             | Oakley
```

I want a query that will select rows where the "Name" value is *not* found in the "orderfrom" column. In this case, it would return the 2nd and 3rd rows, but not the first row (since "ClearVision" is in the orderfrom column).

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `dist`
    JOIN `patientacct`
        ON `patientacct`.dist LIKE CONCAT('%', `dist`.name ,'%')
    INNER JOIN `treasure`
        ON `treasure`.`id` = `patientacct`.`id`
        WHERE (status = 'To Order' AND ****** ORDER BY `name` ASC);
```

The ****** part is where I need help. I have tried this:

```
(( `dist`.name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',`patientacct`.orderfrom,'%')) ))
```

Comment: confused as to what the table looks like, can you post its schema, and a couple of sample rows.

Comment: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=361635.0 posted much better here @Dragon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INNER JOIN `treasure`
        ON `treasure`.`id` = `patientacct`.`id`
WHERE 
    status = 'To Order' 
    AND `dist`.name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',`patientacct`.orderfrom,'%')

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but wouldn't this much simpler code work just fine?

```
mysql> select * from stringComp;
+------------------------------------+---------------+
| value1                             | value2        |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
| ClearVision, Oakley, I-Deal Optics | ClearVision
  |
| ClearVision                        | I-Deal Optics |
| ClearVision                        | Oakley        |
| ClearVision, Oakley, I-Deal Optics | ClearVision   |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the row 1 value 2 has extra whitespace around it.

```
mysql> select * from stringComp where value1 not like concat('%',value2,'%');
+------------------------------------+---------------+
| value1                             | value2        |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
| ClearVision, Oakley, I-Deal Optics | ClearVision
  |
| ClearVision                        | I-Deal Optics |
| ClearVision                        | Oakley        |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This simple SQL compares the contents of column value2 to see if they are in column value1 and returns the rows where they are not.

So, to answer your question, I think this little snippet in the where clause shold get you the right results: *value1 not like concat('%',value2,'%')*

Edit: I just saw the extra line in your query: I think there is an extra bracket in

```
(( `dist`.name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',`patientacct`.orderfrom,'%')) ))
```

Should be:

```
(( `dist`.name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',`patientacct`.orderfrom,'%')))
```

Edit 2: Why do you have all those brackets in there anyhow?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `dist`
    JOIN `patientacct`
        ON `patientacct`.dist LIKE CONCAT('%', `dist`.name ,'%')
    INNER JOIN `treasure`
        ON `treasure`.`id` = `patientacct`.`id`
WHERE 
    status = 'To Order' 
    AND `dist`.name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',`patientacct`.orderfrom,'%')
ORDER BY
    `name` ASC;
```